# compile-time-known array size: passed compilation using g++ but not for icpc

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, struct, icc

The toy code is quite simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define A 10
#define SIZE (int)(ceil(A / 2)) // needs computation but known at compile-time

struct node {
    int keys[SIZE];
};

int main() {
    node a_node;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        a_node.keys[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", a_node.keys[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 test.cpp -o test`, it passes and runs as expected; but using the intel compiler with `icpc -std=c++11 -O3 test.cpp -o test`, an error occurs:

`test.cpp(8): error: function call must have a constant value in a constant expression
    int keys[SIZE];`

Why is it regarded as a function call? But if I used simple arithmetic in the macro (e.g. `#define SIZE (A / 2)`), the error disappears.

gcc version: 4.8.5; icc version: 16.0.3.

Any clue how to solve this issue? Thanks.

------------------ ADDED ------------------

If `int keys[SIZE]` is declared in the main function instead of the struct, i.e. like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define A 10
#define SIZE (int)(ceil(A / 2))

/*struct node {
    int keys[SIZE];
};*/

int main() {
    //node a_node;
    int keys[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        keys[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", keys[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it will pass both gnu and intel compilers. Quite interesting and wierd. I am not sure if I made any mistake that I am not aware of, any possbile clue?

Comment: Are you coding in C or in C++ ? The `c++` tag is suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define A 10
#define SIZE (int)(ceil(A / 2))
```

Your `SIZE`  is *not* a compile-time constant, because `ceil` is a floating point function from `<math.h>`. So the compiler is understanding the variable  `int keys[SIZE];`  as a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA) (whose size is probably computed at *runtime*). Standard C++11 or C++14 don't have VLAs. But GCC accepts them as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length) to the language. Notice that if you declare your `struct node` then `keys` is not a variable but a field or member.

BTW, if you replace the `define` of `SIZE` with

```
 #define SIZE ((A+1)/2)
```

it becomes a compile-time constant (e.g. a `constexpr` in C++ parlance) and has the same value as before.

BTW, your code is not genuine C++11, but looks like C11 code. I would suggest to install a newer version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (in march 2017, use [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/), not some old 4.8). Then use `constexpr`  and `std::array`

VLAs cannot occur as fields in `struct`-s. C99 and C11 have [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) as the possible *last* member of a `struct`. C++11 don't have them.

Probably, your GCC compiler (and the `<math.h>` header) knows that `abs` can be expanded as `__builtin_abs`  which is handled specially by the GCC compiler (but not by others) (so `SIZE` is expanded as `(int)(ceil(10 / 2))` which, with GCC specifically, becomes a compile-time constant thanks to [`__builtin_abs`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html))

You should understand that C and C++ are different languages. If you choose to code in C++ (at least [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), anything older is obsolete in 2017) you should use its standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (and you probably want [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) since the size is runtime computed). If you choose to code in C (at least [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)), consider using flexible array members and allocate your flexible structure in the heap (appropriately using `malloc` or friends). Notice that C++ does not have flexible array members.

Contrarily to your title, your `SIZE` is *not* (according to the standard specifications) a "compile-time-known array size" (but becomes one when optimized by `gcc` or `g++`)

An even better reason to use heap allocation (that is either `std::vector` in C++, or a pointer to some `struct` ending with a flexible array member, or a pointer to an array, in C) is that in practice you'll want to have a much bigger `A` (e.g. `#define A 100000` ...) and it is not reasonable to allocate large data structures on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (often limited to a megabyte or a few of them on current machines and operating systems).

Comment: That's not quite right. VLAs cannot occur as members of structs. What's happening here is that GCC is treating `ceil` as `constexpr`, and Intel isn't. The version that both works on GCC and on Intel is using a VLA on Intel though.